# Javascript: use array.slice() in a loop and not work as expected

Tags: javascript

Can any one help tell me what's wrong with my Javascript code?

```js
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (var i in a) {
  var sliced = a.slice(i + 1);
  console.log(sliced);
}
```

the console log gives: `["one", "two", "three"],[],[],[]`

but what I expected is: `["one", "two", "three"],["two", "three"],["three"],[]`

So, why my code not work? And how should I code? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you use `for..in` loop?

Comment: Tip: log `i + 1` to confirm it’s really `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

Comment: @Rajesh The iteration variable in `for..in` is always a string.

Comment: @Rajesh Not sure why OP uses `for..in`, where current element of iterable  property is a string, not a number?

Comment: @guest271314 I guess OP is playing with different tools to learn. I have added a caveat in your answer. If not required, please revert the edit

Comment: @Rajesh Do not agree with the term "bad practice". A comment  indicating your pov would convey same message, yes?

Comment: its a bad practice to use `for..in` over arrays. `for..in` is more suited to loop over objects. Using `for..in` over arrays will also loop over properties like `length`. So you should avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

You need to parse the string to number since [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement fetches object property which would be `string`. So in the second iteration, it would try to do `a.slice('11')`(string cocatenation `'1' + 1` ==> `'11'`) which returns an empty array.

```js
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (var i in a) {
  var sliced = a.slice(Number(i) + 1);
  console.log(sliced);
}
```

Since it's an array it's better to use a for loop with a counter variable `i` which starts from `1`.

```js
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
  var sliced = a.slice(i);
  console.log(sliced);
}
```

Comment: @Lisa :  glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop to iterate arrays

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var sliced = a.slice(i + 1);
  console.log(sliced);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem :

> why were you trying to do `i+1`?

```js
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
for (var i in a) {
  var sliced = a.slice(i);
  console.log(sliced);
}
```

Comment: Please refer question for desired output and you will see the purpose of `i+1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
var i = 0;
while (i = a.length) {
   console.log(a);
   a.shift();
 }
```